# How to automatically resize the wrapper div using CSS

Tags: css, overflow, wrapper, hidden

I've been struggling with this problem..

There is a wrapper div and it contains 3 vertical column divs with full of texts,
and this wrapper div has red background color so that it can be a background of
the entire texts.

```
<div id="content_wrapper">

    <div id="cside_a">
       // massive texts goes here
    </div>

    ... // two more columns go here.

</div>
```

And here is the CSS code for them.

```
#content_wrapper
{
background-color:#DB0A00;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
min-height:400px;
}
#cside_a, #cside_b, #cside_c
{
float: left;
width: 33%;
}
```

And this code gives me a background that covers only 400px height box..
My expectation was the wrapper div automatically resizes depending on the
size of the divs in it.

Somehow **putting "overflow:hidden" with wrapper CSS code  makes everything work fine**.

I have no idea **why "overflow:hidden" works.. shouldn't this hide all the overflowed texts..?**

Could anyone explain me why?
Is is the correct way to do it anyway?

Comment: overflow:auto works. 'visible' doesn't work.. :( what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that your columns are floating. Take a look at '[Clearfix](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)'

Comment: Ah! This article gives me important things to study. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear your floats. add the following after your third column.

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and this to your css

```
.clear {clear:both;float:none;}
```

Comment: This will work, but requires additional markup. Not my favorite solution, presentation should be (and stay) a CSS thing.

Comment: Ideally of couse I would use advanced CSS selectors to clear the float, but is not compatible in IE6. This is not my favourite solution either - but it is cross browser compatible.